# Product details dont display on sales email or invoice

Tags: product, email

I don't get the product details of sold item on the invoice of sold email.
Any idea how I can get that right?

Comment: Is there any module that uses their own email template?

Comment: Use base theme(set base from admin) to check your email template working proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

check this template exist at location

sales/order/invoice/items.phtml